# Updating high score entry with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Below is segment of code that saves a users high score to parse. It works fine except for the part where it creates a new entry for a user instead of updating the current high score for the user, meaning I could have 10 entries for 'john doe' if John beat his own score 10 times. How can I make it so that parse first checks if the user has a high score and updates it, and only creates a new entry if the user does not have a current high score entry.

```
// Save Highscore to parse using swift.

        let gameScore = PFObject(className:"HighScore")
        gameScore.setObject(currentScore, forKey: "highScore")
        if let _ = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
            gameScore.setObject((PFUser.currentUser()?["name"])!, forKey: "player")
            gameScore.setObject(currentScore, forKey: "highScore")
            //gameScore.setObject((PFUser.currentUser()?["image"])!, forKey: "PlayerImage")
            gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been saved.
                    print("High Score saved to Parse")
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                    print("Error in saving High Score to Parse.")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sample solution in the parse documentation.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
    gameScore["score"] = 1338
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
  }
}
```

[Updating Objects](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-updating-objects)